# Hover effect where overlay starts in one corner and slowly makes its way to another corner

Tags: html, css

I'm looking to create a hover effect where a colored overlay starts in one corner, such as the top right, and slowly moves to another corner, such as the bottom left. During this process, the container (in this case, an image container) will be filled in. In this example, once the colored overlay reached the bottom left, the entire container will be filled.

What's the best pure CSS approach to handle this?

Here's an example of what I'm talking about, but using Javascript: https://www.ducasse-paris.com/en. Scroll down to the "Discover our manufactures of coffee and chocolate" card.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please remember that Stackoverflow isn't a platform to *ask* for things to get **done** for you. It's when you get stuck at producing your own code and can't find a way to fix it.

This is just a little starter for you:

```css
.image-container {
  position: relative;
  line-height: 0;
}

.image {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.image-container::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  background: red;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: 500ms ease-in;
}

.image-container:hover::before {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  opacity: 0.2;
}
```

```html
<div class="image-container">
  <img class="image" src="https://placehold.it/600x900">
</div>
```